# Python program, how to make an atm program loop

Tags: python, loops

How do i make it loop back to the start after doing this? After each transaction, it ends and doesn't go back to see if you can pick another option.
Thanks and it's greatly appreciated.

```
balance=7.52
print("Hi, Welcome to the Atm.")
print("no need for pin numbers, we already know who you are")
print("please selection one of the options given beneath")
print("""
    D = Deposit
    W = Withdrawal
    T = Transfer
    B = Balance check
    Q = Quick cash of 20$
    E = Exit
    Please select in the next line.   
""")
option=input("which option would you like?:")
if option==("D"):
    print("How much would you like to deposit?")
    amount=(int(input("amount:")))
    total=amount+balance
elif option ==("W"):
    print("How much would you like to withdrawl?")
    withdrawl=int(input("how much would you like to take out:?"))
    if balance<withdrawl:
        print("Error, insufficent funds")
        print("please try again")
elif option == "T":
    print("don't worry about the technicalities, we already know who you're          transferring to")
    transfer =int(input("How much would you like to transfer:?"))
    print("you now have", balance-transfer,"dollars in your bank")
elif option=="B":
    print("you currently have",balance,"dollars.")
elif option=="Q":
    print("processing transaction, please await approval")
    quicky=balance-20
    if balance<quicky:
         print("processing transaction, please await approval")
    print("Error, You're broke.:(")
elif option=="E":
      print("Thanks for checking with the Atm")
      print("press the enter key to exit")
```

Comment: i know it's not indented correctly, i'm new to this site and i don't know how to indent correctly.

Comment: Askers here are expected to have a basic working knowledge of programming and to have "done their homework" with respect to a question. "How do I loop?" is such a basic, first-college-course topic that it basically violates both of these categories. Sorry.

Comment: im doing this as a recreational thing, im in highschool and im just a novice. quite a harsh critique

Comment: Please don't take it personally. I only meant to explain my downvote and the others which would likely follow (as I see did happen). You don't have enough rep to chat or I would chat with you about it so I will at least take a look at your code. It's great that you're learning so don't get discouraged; just also don't be surprised if you don't get the best help here (it's just not really what this site does, for better or for worse).

Comment: I'm in high school too, but I've been programming Python and Java for a few years now, so I'll give you some pointers. You need to fix your indentation to reflect different cases and their subsequent statements. Also, use a while loop until the desired case is reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are asking about a loop with a [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value).

Somewhere right before you print your menu, set a sentinel value:

```
keep_going = True
```

Then, preferably on the next line (before you print the first thing you want to see when it loops), you start your loop.

```
while keep_going:   # loop until keep_going == False
```

As written, this is an infinite loop. Everything in the indented block beneath the `while` statement will be repeated, in order, forever. That's obviously not what we want -- we have to have some way to get out so we can use our computer for other things! That's where our sentinel comes in.

Build in a new menu option to allow the user to quit. Suppose you key that to "Q", and the user picks it. Then, in that branch:

```
elif option == 'Q':
    keep_going = False
```

Since that's all there is in that branch, we "fall off" the bottom of the loop, then go back to the `while` statement, which now fails its check. Loop terminated!

By the way, you should think about reading [The Python Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It's very easy to read and gives you an idea how to make your code also very easy to read. Most every Python programmer abides by it and expects others to do the same, so you should too! If you want help learning it, or aren't sure if you're doing it right, there are [tools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8) to [check your code](http://www.pylint.org/) to help you keep it clean and error-free.

Happy programming!

Comment: truly appreciate it, thanks alot! I'll be sure to enlighten myself with the guide